# Wireshark not capturing packets above network layer

Tags: tcp, udp, wireshark, packet

I have no filters applied, but am not seeing any traffic other than what appear to be conversations at the Link Layer between my computer's NIC and the router.  It is connected via Ethernet, and I believe at one time I could see HTTP, TCP, UDP, etc.
[image]

Any suggestions would be appreciated.  I've tried visiting Websites and received nothing clearly from those sites.

Comment: Because it is showing `0x0800` in the protocol field, I'm guessing IPV4 is not enabled.  Go to Analyze->Enabled Protocols and make sure IPV4 is checked.

Comment: @JimD. - Thank you.  Good grief, I can't believe that was it.  I could have sworn they were all enabled, but sure enough - IPv4 was disabled.